# Compartilhar pasta de trabalho com VBA

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Preciso compartilhar um pasta de trabalho na rede, porém ao executar o código o arquivo vai para a pasta `C:\Documents\`.

Qual seria a solução para este problema?

```vb
Private Sub btExecuta_Click()
    Dim NovoNomeArquivo As String
    Dim vPlan           As Worksheet

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    '- Remover o Compartilhamento
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.ExclusiveAccess '- Acesso Exclusivo
    On Error GoTo 0

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    '- Mesclar Celulas
    ActiveSheet.Range("B3:C7").Merge

    '-- SALVA CÓPIA DA PLANILHA EM DETERMINADO PERIODO

    '-- Salva Pasta de trabalho antes de duplicar
    ActiveWorkbook.Save

    '-- Verifica o caminho onde esta salvo a pasta de trabalho
    NovoNomeArquivo = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Mid$(ActiveWorkbook.Name, 1, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 5) _
                    & " - " & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsm"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs NovoNomeArquivo

    '-- PROTEGER AS PLANILHAS COM SENHA
    'Com exceção da planilha INSTRUÇÃO
    '-- Ignora a pergunta se quer salvar
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    '-- BLOQUEIA TODAS AS PLANILHAS
    For Each vPlan In Sheets
        If vPlan.Name <> "INSTRUÇÃO" Then
            vPlan.Protect Password:="123"
        End If
    Next vPlan

    '-- COMPARTILHA A PLANILHA
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ActiveWorkbook.Name, accessmode:=xlShared
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    MsgBox " Processo Concluído", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

fernandosavio,

Pode ser que o lance não seja código, mas características do documento Excel...
   ... por favor, veja isso:

> Compartilhar uma pasta de trabalho
>
> 1 - Crie uma nova pasta de trabalho ou abra uma pasta de trabalho
>   existente que deseja disponibilizar para compartilhamento.
>
> 2 - Na guia Revisão, no grupo Alterações, clique em Compartilhar Pasta
>   de Trabalho.
>
> 3 - Na caixa de diálogo Compartilhar Pasta de Trabalho, na guia
>   Edição, marque a caixa de seleção Permitir alterações por mais de um
>   usuário ao mesmo tempo. Permite também mesclar a pasta de trabalho.
>
> 4 - Na guia Avançado, selecione as opções que deseja usar para
>   controlar e atualizar alterações e clique em OK.
>
> 5 - Na caixa de diálogo salvar como, insira um local de rede na Barra
>   de endereços.
>
> 6 - Siga um destes procedimentos:
>
> 6.1 - Se essa é uma nova pasta de trabalho, informe um nome na caixa de diálogo Nome do arquivo e clique em Salvar.
>
> 6.2 - Se for uma pasta de trabalho existente, clique em Salvar.
>
> 7 - Envie um email para as pessoas que compartilharão a pasta de
>   trabalho. Na mensagem, inclua o local do arquivo e solicite que criem
>   uma cópia da pasta de trabalho para uso próprio, mantendo todas as
>   cópias na pasta com a original.

Veja também em:

[Usar uma pasta de trabalho compartilhada para colaborar no Excel 2016 para Windows](https://www.tudoexcel.com.br/planilhas/usar-uma-pasta-de-trabalho-compartilhada-para-colaborar-no-excel-2016-para-windows-930.html)

[]'s,
Fabio I.